# configuration for haproxy in ubuntu?

Tags: haproxy

I'm getting the following problem when I'm configuring haproxy stats:

> Job for haproxy.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status haproxy.service" and "journalctl
>   -xe" for details.

Below is my configuration file code:

```
listen  stats   192.168.10.10:1936
        mode            http
        log             global    
        maxconn         10    
        clitimeout      100s
        srvtimeout      100s
        contimeout      100s
        timeout queue   100s
        stats enable
        stats hide-version
        stats refresh 30s
        stats show-node
        stats auth admin:password
        stats uri  /haproxy?stats

global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend haproxy_in
    bind *:80
    default_backend haproxy_http

backend haproxy_http
    balance roundrobin
    mode http
    server ironman 104.211.241.39:80 
    server thor 104.211.246.147:80
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you run journalctl -xe or view your log file you would see you have severe config problems

> 'listen' cannot handle unexpected argument '192.168.10.10:1936'.
>   parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:1] : please use the 'bind' keyword
>   for listening addresses. Error(s) found in configuration file :
>   /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

Place the keyword "bind" infront of your stats ip:port , i.e:

```
listen  stats
        bind            192.168.10.10:1936
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it due to the latest version of haproxy?

Comment: which version of haproxy u r using